# iframe - dynamic height/width possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm appending an iframe into a div using jQuery.
I'd like it to take the full width/height of the div.
Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to add the style attribute 'style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" '?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

you can set the frame.height = div.offsetHeight property (it should includes padding)...
Same for the width.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <h1>
        I'm H1
    </h1>
</div>

<script>
    alert(document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight);
</script>
```

If you try this code you can see that changing the H1 with P or Span the offsetHeight will change.

So you can:

```
var h = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;   
$('#myFrame').attr('height', h);
```